# How to add items to a list from an array javascript

Tags: javascript

What is wrong with this code? I just started programming Javascript, thanks so much!

```
    <script>
    var select = document.getElementById("GameSelect");
for(var temp = 0; i > Links.length; temp++) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.text = LinkName[temp];
    option.value = LinkName[temp];
    select.add(option, 0);
}
    </script>
```

Comment: What  is Links.length? Is that supposed to be the select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close, just a couple mistakes

```
var select = document.getElementById("GameSelect");

for(var temp=0; temp<Links.length; temp++) {
  var option = document.createElement('option');
  option.textContent = Links[temp];
  option.value = Links[temp];
  select.appendChild(option);
}
```

---

Other things to note,

- JavaScript uses camelCase: your array should probably be called `links`
- `elem.textContent` is the attribute you want to set; not `elem.text`

  You could also use `elem.innerHTML`
- If you don't have to support IE < 9, you can use [arr.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

  ```
  Links.forEach(function(link) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.textContent = link;
    option.value = link;
    select.appendChild(option);
  });
  ```